# Spark-Submit is throwing exception when running in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

i have a simple spark app for learning puprose ... this scala program parallelizr the data List and writes the RDD on a file in Hadoop.

```
import  org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object HelloSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HelloSPark1").setMaster(args(0))
     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
     val i = List(1,4,2,11,23,45,67,8,909,5,1,8,"agarwal",19,11,12,34,8031,"aditya")
     val b = sc.parallelize(i,3)
     b.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
  }

}

i create a jar file and when i run it on my cluster it throws error when i run it  as --master YARN and --deploy-mode cluster using following command

    spark-submit --class "HelloSpark" --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster sparkappl_2.11-1.0.jar  yarn /user
    /letsbigdata9356/sparktest/run6

            client token: N/A
             diagnostics: Application application_1483332319047_3791 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1483332319047_3791_000002 e
    xited with  exitCode: 15
    For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://a.cloudxlab.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1483332319047_3791Then, click on
     links to logs of each attempt.
    Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
    Container id: container_e77_1483332319047_3791_02_000001
    Exit code: 15
    Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=15: 
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15
    Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15
    Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
             ApplicationMaster host: N/A
             ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
             queue: default
             start time: 1484231621733
             final status: FAILED
             tracking URL: http://a.cloudxlab.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1483332319047_3791
             user: letsbigdata9356
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1483332319047_3791 finished with failed status
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:974)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1020)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:685)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    17/01/12 14:34:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

but when i run it using following command in yarn-client mode or local mode it works fine

```
spark-submit --class "HelloSpark" sparkappl_2.11-1.0.jar yarn-client /user/letsbigdata9356/sparktest/run
5

or

spark-submit --class "HelloSpark" sparkappl_2.11-1.0.jar local /user/letsbigdata9356/sparktest/run
7
```

I am new to spark cloud you please help me resolving and learning about this issue.

Comment: try passing the datanucleus jar in ur spark-submit command using the --jars option.

Comment: @RajatMishra thanks for answering... what is the datanucleus jar?

Comment: basically there are 3 datanucleus jars which are required for spark processing and can be found in the spark folder. when u run in client mode , these jar already present because then only able to run spark-shell. Folowing are jars required..datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar

Comment: did it work for you?